# Problem related to linear transformation and its image and kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the following linear transformation: $$ L \in {ℝ}^{3,2} $$ which is defined through 2 vectors: $ \quad L \left(\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}\right)  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \vec{v_1} \quad $ and $ \quad  L \left(\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \vec{v_2} $

I need to:

1. Prove whether $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ are linearly independent or not.
2. Find $im(L)$ and its basis.
3. Check if vector $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ is located within $ker(L)$ or not.

Here're my ideas:

1. I assume, that $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ are indeed linearly independent, as there's no such $\alpha$, which could get $\vec{v_2}$ when multiplied with $\vec{v_1}$.
2. I believe $im(L)$ is $span\{\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2}\}$. Since both vectors are probably linearly independent, basis should be the same. (?)
3. I have absolutely no idea how to get $ker(L)$ if I don't even have a matrix to begin with. :(

Unfortunately I can't seem to actually prove my assumptions and don't even have an idea of how I could solve part 3. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Try setting $v_1$ and $v_2$ in a matrix, and try row reduction to see if they're linearly independent (they clearly are but this should suffice as a proof). Also, the input vectors are linearly independent (try a matrix proof again), so you can use them as a basis in $\Bbb R^2$ to construct your matrix, which may give insight into the answers for questions 2 and 3.

Comment: What's the reason of the downvote? A downvote without any advice on how to improve the question is completly unconstructive